# Having some issue with vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm testing the VLOOKUP function with different sheets. I have created a sheet1 as my data reference table and sheet2 as where data is supposed to be filled with reference to the Name. I just don't know what is wrong with the formula. It keeps giving the #ref!.

Below is the formula that I'm using.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,2,FALSE)
```

**SHEET1**

[image: Sheet1]

**SHEET2**

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: You have not selected a matrix with a 2nd column. Use `A$2:B$6` in the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument should include the ID column from Sheet1. Like below:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```

The way **Vlookup** works is - it looks for the value of `A2` in the **first column** in `$A$2:$B$6` and returns the `2`nd column with Exact Match (`FALSE`)

- So if you change the 3rd argument(`2`) to 3, then the range should have a minimum of 3 columns like `$A$2:$C$6`

Answer (score 0):

You can try change argument 4th to 0 and change $A$2:$A$6 to $A$2:$B$6

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

#REf occurs when your reference is not valid .See ,You referenced $A$2:$A$6,It is not valid ,As your array in sheet1 is extended to B6 .
Use this:=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)